# why do i get "Error unepexted symbol in"

Tags: r

I am trying to read many csv files
When i read one of the files not using a value, it works

I have a list of file named `list.of.files` like so:

```
#[1] "2013ARI.EVN" "2013ATL.EVN" "2013CHN.EVN" "2013CIN.EVN" "2013COL.EVN"
#[6] "2013LAN.EVN" "2013MIA.EVN" "2013MIL.EVN" "2013NYN.EVN" "2013PHI.EVN"
#[11] "2013PIT.EVN" "2013SDN.EVN" "2013SFN.EVN" "2013SLN.EVN" "2013WAS.EVN"
```

so i can make a for loop i tested `assign()` like this

```
name<-substr(list.of.files[1],1,7)
assign(name,read.csv(paste(name,".csv",sep="")))
summary(ARI2013)

#Error in summary(ARI2013) : object 'ARI2013' not found
```

what is wrong with the way i am assigning?

Comment: try `summary("2013ARI")`

Comment: @DavidArenburg that actually gives the summary of the one item long character vector `c("2013ARI")`. You need to combine it with `get` to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assign` creates an R object with the name you pass as a string. You passed `2013ARI` as input, but refer to `ARI2013` in `summary`. The error you see is simply because you did not use the correct object name. The second problem here is that you start your variable name with a number, which does not work well in R. You could use `get` to obtain the object nonetheless:

```
> substr("2013ARI.EVN", 1, 7)
[1] "2013ARI"
> assign(substr("2013ARI.EVN", 1, 7), 1)
> summary(get("2013ARI"))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      1       1       1       1       1       1
```

Do note however, using `assign` to creates groups of objects is not the best way in R. I would put the set of csv files in a list:

```
list_of_files = sprintf("%s.csv", substr(c("2013ARI.EVN", "2013ATL.EVN"), 1, 7))
list_of_data_frames = lapply(list_of_files, read.csv)
```

Comment: Thank you i tried using lapply and got an error in read table no lines available

Comment: OK it is the number at the begining